# Antd UI Table: Dynamically add/delete columns

Tags: reactjs, html-table, antd

Based on ANTD's Table example: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell, I would like to replicate this, with the addition of having the ability to add/delete new columns. The sample from the link above only illustrates how to add new rows.

Here's the code from the sample:

```
import { Table, Input, Button, Popconfirm, Form } from 'antd';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const EditableContext = React.createContext();

const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }) => (
  <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
    <tr {...props} />
  </EditableContext.Provider>
);

const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);

class EditableCell extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editing: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.editable) {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.props.editable) {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
    }
  }

  toggleEdit = () => {
    const editing = !this.state.editing;
    this.setState({ editing }, () => {
      if (editing) {
        this.input.focus();
      }
    });
  }

  handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    const { editing } = this.state;
    if (editing && this.cell !== e.target && !this.cell.contains(e.target)) {
      this.save();
    }
  }

  save = () => {
    const { record, handleSave } = this.props;
    this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      this.toggleEdit();
      handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { editing } = this.state;
    const {
      editable,
      dataIndex,
      title,
      record,
      index,
      handleSave,
      ...restProps
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <td ref={node => (this.cell = node)} {...restProps}>
        {editable ? (
          <EditableContext.Consumer>
            {(form) => {
              this.form = form;
              return (
                editing ? (
                  <FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                    {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
                      rules: [{
                        required: true,
                        message: `${title} is required.`,
                      }],
                      initialValue: record[dataIndex],
                    })(
                      <Input
                        ref={node => (this.input = node)}
                        onPressEnter={this.save}
                      />
                    )}
                  </FormItem>
                ) : (
                  <div
                    className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
                    style={{ paddingRight: 24 }}
                    onClick={this.toggleEdit}
                  >
                    {restProps.children}
                  </div>
                )
              );
            }}
          </EditableContext.Consumer>
        ) : restProps.children}
      </td>
    );
  }
}

class EditableTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.columns = [{
      title: 'name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      width: '30%',
      editable: true,
    }, {
      title: 'age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
    }, {
      title: 'address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
    }, {
      title: 'operation',
      dataIndex: 'operation',
      render: (text, record) => (
        this.state.dataSource.length >= 1
          ? (
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}>
              <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          ) : null
      ),
    }];

    this.state = {
      dataSource: [{
        key: '0',
        name: 'Edward King 0',
        age: '32',
        address: 'London, Park Lane no. 0',
      }, {
        key: '1',
        name: 'Edward King 1',
        age: '32',
        address: 'London, Park Lane no. 1',
      }],
      count: 2,
    };
  }

  handleDelete = (key) => {
    const dataSource = [...this.state.dataSource];
    this.setState({ dataSource: dataSource.filter(item => item.key !== key) });
  }

  handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
    const newData = {
      key: count,
      name: `Edward King ${count}`,
      age: 32,
      address: `London, Park Lane no. ${count}`,
    };
    this.setState({
      dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
      count: count + 1,
    });
  }

  handleSave = (row) => {
    const newData = [...this.state.dataSource];
    const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, {
      ...item,
      ...row,
    });
    this.setState({ dataSource: newData });
  }

  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;
    const components = {
      body: {
        row: EditableFormRow,
        cell: EditableCell,
      },
    };
    const columns = this.columns.map((col) => {
      if (!col.editable) {
        return col;
      }
      return {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave,
        }),
      };
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleAdd} type="primary" style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          Add a row
        </Button>
        <Table
          components={components}
          rowClassName={() => 'editable-row'}
          bordered
          dataSource={dataSource}
          columns={columns}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EditableTable />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make your columns array a part of the state and update it through setState.

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/gges5110/pen/GLPjYr?editors=0010

```
// State
this.state = {
  dataSource: [{
    key: '0',
    name: 'Edward King 0',
    age: '32',
    address: 'London, Park Lane no. 0',
  }, {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Edward King 1',
    age: '32',
    address: 'London, Park Lane no. 1',
  }],
  columns: [{
    title: 'name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    width: '30%',
    editable: true,
  }, {
    title: 'age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
  }]
};

// Event to add new column
handleAddColumn = () => {
  const { columns } = this.state;
  const newColumn = {
    title: 'age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
  };

  this.setState({
    columns: [...columns, newColumn]
  });
}

// Render method
render() {
  const { dataSource, columns } = this.state;
  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={columns}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your example. Sadly when opening your link to CodePen the table is not rendered. I would love to use your example to build a similar functionality. My challenge I want to add a row and edit it in-place and online persist it to the "state" when I save the data. If I instead cancel the row editing this should remove the row as well. How can I do this easily? Is there a way I could build this with generic components?

Comment: I didn't ping the library to a fixed version so it was using the latest version, it should be fixed now. On persisting the state, this example is mainly for showcasing how one could go about adding/deleting the columns dynamically. I've got another example for resetting the rows: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gges5110/ant-design-table-form

Comment: you are amazing, this is exactly what I searched for! Thanks